# Which valediction should I use with my boss?

Tags: formality, email, valediction

I work as a freelancer for a company and I do most of my communication via e-mails.

My boss usually ends his mails with "cheers" whereas I always use "regards".

Are there any alternatives to "regards" that will be formal but not too formal?

Comment: If you usually use "Regards" there is no reason to stop unless you want to [mirror](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mirroring_%28psychology%29)

Comment: What's the problem you're having with 'regards?'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are numerous sign-off phrases used in letters, but most e-mails are more succinct, often forgoing closing phrases and even omitting a name at the end (because it presumably appears in the **To** box). This is especially true if there is a standard signature block containing business card-like information at the end of the message, often automatically generated.

If you feel a closing phrase is necessary, there are many possibilities including

> - Thanks
> - Thank you
> - Sincerely
> - Sincerely yours
> - Best
> - Yours
> - Yours truly

Many of these are fairly formal for e-mail.

Why not consider responding just as your boss does  and say **cheers**?

*[All of the above reflects a US point of view and may not be applicable in other countries. I tend to be more formal when corresponding with colleagues overseas.]*